# Login to Admin panel successfully but having issue in the dashboard "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page." magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

[image: Error message at dashboard]

I can be able to login to my store admin easily and everything is working fine. After when I logged in I got an error "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.
" at the dashboard.
It is just for the first time issue. When I refresh the page everything works fine. Whenever I login to my store admin I got this issue. The occurrence of the issue is when I upgrade my magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3.
Please help me out with it. Thanks!

Comment: achievable solver? I have the same problem, but on the product catalog page

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue after upgrading from 2.3.6 to 2.4.3 on initial login to admin area. Clears when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes described here to ger rid of this message:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33749#issuecomment-908145941

The file in mention is found here:
`\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php`